# Tabs feature in macOs for not document-based apps

Tags: xcode, tabs, macos-sierra, nstabview

In Xcode 8 under macOs Sierra it is possible to create a document-based app and it automatically is capable of showing different opened documents in tabs just as Safari or Xcode itself did prior to macOs Sierra. Now, I like to know if I can use this in a different context as well. Imagine an App where the user can load a book from a dropdown menu. I like the chapters of that book be selectable via a tab view. A standard NSTabView however does not look as nice as the one I mentioned earlier, so that is not an option.

Comment: Are you able to add this feature in non-document based application ?

Comment: @ParagBafna: Yes I am. I can post the code later if you like.

Comment: Please add your code in answer. Thanks.